# How do I consume a non-wcf rest service in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple web service I wrote using Webmatrix that returns data in json. I liked to consume that service using ASP.NET MVC 3. I know how to do this with WCF but we are not going to use WCF on this project. Is there something akin to jquery's getJson() method in ASP.NET MVC where I just pass in the restful url and it returns the data and I handle it in a callback? Thanks for any help :-)

Here's my service:

URL:

```
 /services/GetAllItemsService
```

Code:

```
@{
    var items = ItemsService.GetAllItems();

    Json.Write(items, Response.Output);
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) to fetch the JSON data from a remote resource. For example:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string json = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/services/GetAllItemsService");

    // TODO: do something with this JSON data, like for example deserialize into a model
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var model = serializer.Deserialize<SomeModel>(json);
}
```

Or if you wanted to write the JSON directly to the output:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string json = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/services/GetAllItemsService");
    Response.Output.Write(json);
}
```

Comment: Hello, how to post multiple objects through webclient

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RESTSharp: http://restsharp.org/

Answer (score 0):

- Use some lib like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), [Hammock](https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock), ...
- Retrieve the data with WebClient and use a JSON deserializer like `JavaScriptSerializer` or [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)